# Experiment and unity3D (coroutine, timer and specific conditions)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path

[Edited] Hello everyone,

I have some problems with a script "Follower" i'm modifying (got it from the pathCreator Asset). I have been working on it for hours but i am now limited by my knowledge and abilities.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

The participant of my experiment will have to answer questions related to my experience orally. Therefore, and to avoid getting used to timing, I would like to randomize when the FPScharacter stops. By stopping every 4, 8 or 12 seconds randomly, the participant will not be able to get used to the timings. If the FPScharacter stops every 4 seconds, the participant will get used to it and could implement response strategies biasing my results.

So I would like to do the following:

1. The FPScharacter begins its journey at the starting point of the path (using pathcreator from the asset store), moving at constant speed
2. After [4, 8, 12 seconds], it stops (I deactivate the movement script of the FPScharacter). At the same time, an object appears. This "stop" and appearance of the object must last 4 seconds (no randomization on this timing there).
3. After 4 seconds of stop, the FPSCharacter sets out again on the way
4. After [4, 8, 12] seconds, it stops again, a new object appears for 4 seconds, then the FPScharacter starts again
5. Repeat

I want to be able to do this as many times as I have items to present.
**The comments on my code are less important than the explanation shown just before ! **

So to summarize : Walking for (4 or 8 or 12 secondes choosen randomly) - Stop for 4 secondes (and in the same time an object spawn) - (End of 4 secondes) object disapear and  FPS start walking again for (4 or 8 or 12 secondes choosen randomly) ....

**Remember** : I am not a pro at programming and only know how to do stuff on C# so i wont be able to translate any code in java to c#. ALl i basically do is copy-paste codes and try my best to modify it so it suits my needs. But my abilities are limited.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PathCreation;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

// I AM USING THE PATHFOLLOWER SCRIPT FROM PATHCREATOR ASSET 
// (i copy pasted it from the folder so i still have the original
// and can modify this one to add the timers and objects spawning conditions)

// Put this script on the FPScontroller
// Specify the pathCreator (object created with a unity assets and that is basicaly a draw line in the environnement that objects can follow)
// Depending on the end of path instruction, will either loop, reverse, or stop at the end of the path.

public class Follower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PathCreator pathCreator; //Object PathCreator to put specify in Unity (gameObject with specifics scripts)
    public EndOfPathInstruction instructionFinChemin; //Variable that ask if the FPScontroller needs to stop/loop/reverse at the end of the path
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public float speedOfPlayer = 5; //Speed of the FPScontroller
    float distanceTravelled; //Used to calculate the distance the FPS will need to walk

    //Variable used to count time in secondes
    private int secondsTimer;
    private float timer = 0.0f;

    public GameObject Clone; 
    public Transform SpawnArea; //Used to specify where the item will spawn
    public GameObject ItemSpawning; //Object that will spawn (like a flower, a baloon or whatever)

    private bool enter = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (pathCreator != null)
        {
            // Subscribed to the pathUpdated event so that we're notified if the path changes during the game
            pathCreator.pathUpdated += OnPathChanged;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //using this to get the time passed in secondes integer
        timer += Time.time;
        secondsTimer = (int)(timer % 60);

        /*Condition : if the path exist and [4,8,12] secondes have not still passed, move the FPScharacter along the path
        - HERE I NEED HELP : How do i do so it select randomly (after each stop) 
        that it will check for 4 - 8 or 12 secondes and not only for 4 secondes
        - Like : Walk automatically along the path --> 4 secondes after --> Stop for 4 secondes and spawn an Object --- 
                  -->  Walk automatically --> 8 secondes after --> Stop for 4 secondes and spawn an object ... and so forth*/

        if (pathCreator != null & (secondsTimer % 4 != 0))
        {
            distanceTravelled += speedOfPlayer * Time.deltaTime;
            // Instruction permettant le déplacement de l'objet le long du path
            transform.position = pathCreator.path.GetPointAtDistance(distanceTravelled, instructionFinChemin);
            transform.rotation = pathCreator.path.GetRotationAtDistance(distanceTravelled, instructionFinChemin); 
        }
        //If the path exist and [4,8,12] seconds have passed (I need it to be 4 or 8 or 12 secondes choosen randomly - as explained before in the comment of the script)
        else if (pathCreator != null & (secondsTimer % 4 == 0))
        {
            //cloning my gameobject in the environnement so i can destroy it later. Dont know if i am doing mistakes here
            Clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(ItemSpawning, SpawnArea.position, SpawnArea.rotation);

            //Even if the FPScontriller is disabled in this loop, i still want him to watch and stay in the same direction
            transform.position = pathCreator.path.GetPointAtDistance(distanceTravelled, instructionFinChemin);
            transform.rotation = pathCreator.path.GetRotationAtDistance(distanceTravelled, instructionFinChemin);

            //Disable de FPScontroller Movement Script
            GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = false; 

            //tried to use a coroutine so i can tell my script : wait for 4 secondes
            //so using a coroutine with waitforsecondes but it isnt working

            if (enter == false)
            {
                StartCoroutine(DelayLoadLevel());
            }


        }

        Destroy(Clone);
        GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = true;
    }

    //fonction Coroutine pour delay le temps de redémarrage du personnage de 4 secondes
    IEnumerator DelayLoadLevel()
    {
        enter = true;
        Debug.Log("Your enter Coroutine at" + Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        enter = false;
    }




    // If the path changes during the game, update the distance travelled so that the follower's position on the new path
    // is as close as possible to its position on the old path
    void OnPathChanged()
    {
        distanceTravelled = pathCreator.path.GetClosestDistanceAlongPath(transform.position);
    }
}
```

Right now the only thing that works is the movement of the FPScharacter along the path (but it doesnt take into account my timers, nor stop, nor spawn or destroy objects). 
I am also trying to implement a list of gameObjects that contains the objects i will spawn in the environment, without succes >>

Can anyone help me there ? :D

### ----------------------------------------------------------

Alright,

With your help, i managed to make my character move for 4 seconds, then stop for 4 secondes, then move for 4 secondes, so on and so forth.

I will jump into the [4, 8, 12] randomization later, as it is not my major problem right now.

Right now, i cant figure out why my `RigidBodyFPSController` rotates to Y = -180 everytime it stops. I tried to freeze it by using `Rigidbody.freezeRotation = true` before `WaitforSeconds(4)` is called, without succes. I even tried to disable the `RigidBodyFPScontroller` but it does some odd things (screen jumping and vibrating like there is a conflict between 2 movement function).

Using prints, i figured that the rotation to y = -180 happends when waitforSeconds(4) is called. But i dont know why.

Any idea ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PathCreation;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

// I AM USING THE PATHFOLLOWER SCRIPT FROM PATHCREATOR ASSET (modified to my will)

// Put this script on the FPScontroller
// Specify the pathCreator (object created with a unity assets and that is basicaly a draw line in the environnement that objects can follow)
// Depending on the end of path instruction, will either loop, reverse, or stop at the end of the path.

public class Follower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PathCreator pathCreator; //Object PathCreator to put specify in Unity (gameObject with specifics scripts)
    public EndOfPathInstruction instructionFinChemin; //Variable that ask if the FPScontroller needs to stop/loop/reverse at the end of the path
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public float speedOfPlayer = 5; //Speed of the FPScontroller
    float distanceTravelled; //Used to calculate the distance the FPS will need to walk

    //Variable used to count time in secondes
    private int timer = 0;

    public GameObject Clone; //Trying to use this variable as the Clone of my Object that will spawn in the environnement and then will be destroyed
    public Transform SpawnArea; //Used to specify where the item will spawn
    public GameObject ItemSpawning; //Object that will spawn (like a flower, a baloon or whatever)

    //Used to select randomly after each stop a seconde between 4, 8, 12
    public int[] ListTiming;
    static Random rnd = new Random();



/*    private void Awake()
    {
        ListTiming = new int[3];
        ListTiming[1] = 4;
        ListTiming[1] = 8;
        ListTiming[1] = 12;
        int Timing = ListTiming[Random.Range(0, ListTiming.Length)];
    }*/


    void Start()
    {
        if (pathCreator != null)
        {
            // Subscribed to the pathUpdated event so that we're notified if the path changes during the game
            pathCreator.pathUpdated += OnPathChanged;
        }
        //Used to count time and trigger stops
        StartCoroutine(DelayLoadLevel());
    }


    void Update()
    {
        print(timer);
        if (pathCreator != null & (timer % 4 != 0))
        {
            distanceTravelled += speedOfPlayer * Time.deltaTime; // se fait à chaque frame
            // Instruction permettant le déplacement de l'objet le long du path
            transform.position = pathCreator.path.GetPointAtDistance(distanceTravelled, instructionFinChemin);
            // instruction pour permettre la rotation le long du path 
            transform.rotation = pathCreator.path.GetRotationAtDistance(distanceTravelled, instructionFinChemin);
            //GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = true;

        }
    }

        //fonction Coroutine pour delay le temps de redémarrage du personnage de 4 secondes
        IEnumerator DelayLoadLevel()
    {
        print("DelayLoadLevel");
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            timer = timer + 1;

            print("time = " + timer);
            if (pathCreator != null && timer % 4 == 0)
            {
                print("time");
                Debug.Log("Your enter DelayLoadLevel at " + timer);
                //GameObject.Find("FPSController").GetComponent<RigidbodyFirstPersonController>().enabled = false;
                Rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
                print("Entre dans wait for seconds : " + Time.time);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
                //GameObject.Find("FPSController").GetComponent<RigidbodyFirstPersonController>().enabled = true;
                Rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
                print("Entre dans wait for seconds : " + Time.time);
            }
        }
    }

    // If the path changes during the game, update the distance travelled so that the follower's position on the new path
    // is as close as possible to its position on the old path
    void OnPathChanged()
    {
        distanceTravelled = pathCreator.path.GetClosestDistanceAlongPath(transform.position);
    }
}
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Alright,

my problem was caused by a conflict between the `RigidBodyFPScontroller` script and the `PathCreator` Script that apply transform rotation and movement. Disabling the `RigidBodyFPScontroller` Script removed the problem.

Now, i need to figure out why, when my `RigidBodyFPSController` stops, it goes higher in space (from Y = 0 to Y ~0.8) - see the screen shots below. To describe the behavior, its like just before it stop, the `RigidBodyFPSController`jumps and freeze at that height. But can't figure why either.

[image: my <code>RigidBodyFPSController</code> moving along the path]

[image: my <code>RigidBodyFPSController</code> stoping and changing height for some reason]

Comment: Hi, comments in the code dont seem to match the question - so Im not entirely sure what you want help with. However there seems to be a stop thing in the path creator, you could trigger and then resume that... If stopping/starting seems to be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright everyone,

I managed to do some of the stuff i wanted. I forget about the 4-8-12 secondes randomization, as it was to hard to implement for me.

But you will find anything else working. What the script does is let you choose how many `gameObject`you want to spawn and how many `transform` associated to those `gameObject`. For my experiment, i had to show first static Item (`ìtemFixe`), then mobile item (`ìtemMobile`) and then mixed item, which mean static and mobile item (`itemMixte`).

Those item will spawn to the transform location you specified earlier and will be destroy after 4 secondes (`Destroy(instantiate...), 4)`). 
Your `RigidBodyFPSController`will move along a path created with PATHCREATOR unity asset.

Here's my script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PathCreation;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

// I AM USING THE PATHFOLLOWER SCRIPT FROM PATHCREATOR UNITY ASSET (modified to my will) 
//      All function besides what's inside the void update and void onPathchange functions have been made manually

// Put this script on the FPScontroller
// Specify the pathCreator (object created with a unity assets and that is basicaly a draw line using bezieLine in the environnement that objects can follow)
// Depending on the end of path instruction, will either loop, reverse, or stop at the end of the path.

public class Follower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PathCreator pathCreator; // Object PathCreator to put specify in Unity (gameObject with specifics scripts)
    public EndOfPathInstruction instructionFinChemin; // Variable that ask if the FPScontroller needs to stop/loop/reverse at the end of the path
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public float speedOfPlayer = 5; // Speed of the FPScontroller
    float distanceTravelled; // Used to calculate the distance the FPS will need to walk

    // Variable used to count time in secondes
    private int timer = 0;

    // Used for spawning items (itemFixe) in a specific location (spawnPoint) using randomization
    // 3 listes de gameObject (items fixe, mobile ou mixte) associés à 3 listes de trandform (spawnPoint fixe, mobile, mixte)
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject[] itemFixe;
    public GameObject[] itemMobile;
    public GameObject[] itemMixte;

    public Transform[] spawnPoint;
    public Transform[] spawnPointMobile;
    public Transform[] spawnPointMixte;

    // Variables for the Spawn function : 
    //      indexPosition used to check the spawnPoint[indexPosition] transform
    //      indexItem used to check the item[indexItemn] gameObject
    //      compteur used to check 'if' condition
    private int indexPositionFixe = 0;
    private int indexPositionMobile = 0;
    private int indexPositionMixte = 0;
    private int compteurFixe = 0;
    private int compteurMobile = 0;
    private int compteurMixte = 0;
    private int indexItemFixe = 0;
    private int indexItemMobile = 0;
    private int indexItemMixte = 0;



    void Start()
    {
        // Used to count time and trigger stops
        StartCoroutine(DelayLoadLevel());

        // To assure RigidBodyFPSController Script will not interfer with PathCreator Script
        GameObject.Find("RigidBodyFPSController").GetComponent<RigidbodyFirstPersonController>().enabled = false;

        // Randomize prefabs using the RandomizeArray function
        RandomizeArray<GameObject>(itemFixe);
        RandomizeArray<GameObject>(itemMobile);
        RandomizeArray<GameObject>(itemMixte);

        // Linked to the pathUpdated event : notified if the path changes during the game
        if (pathCreator != null)
        {
            pathCreator.pathUpdated += OnPathChanged;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (pathCreator != null & (timer % 4 != 0))
        {

            distanceTravelled += speedOfPlayer * Time.deltaTime;
            // Movement along the path
            transform.position = pathCreator.path.GetPointAtDistance(distanceTravelled, instructionFinChemin);
            // Rotation along the path
            transform.rotation = pathCreator.path.GetRotationAtDistance(distanceTravelled, instructionFinChemin);
        }
    }

    // Fonction Coroutine to count time and stop RigidBodyFPSController for 4 secondes
    IEnumerator DelayLoadLevel()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            timer = timer + 1;
            print("timer = " + timer);

            if (pathCreator != null && timer % 4 == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Enter IF timer == 4 secondes");
                Spawn();
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
            }
        }
    }

    //public static void RemoveAt(ref T[] array, int index);

    void Spawn()
    {
        Debug.Log("Enter Spawn function");
        if (compteurFixe < itemFixe.Length)
        {
            Debug.Log("Boucle ITEM FIXE ");
            Debug.Log("indexArrayItemFixe " + indexItemFixe);
            Debug.Log("indexPositionItemFixe " + indexPositionFixe);
            Debug.Log("compteur de la boucle IF " + compteurFixe);
            Destroy(Instantiate(itemFixe[indexItemFixe], spawnPoint[indexPositionFixe].position, spawnPoint[indexPositionFixe].rotation), 4);
            Debug.Log("Item spawned : " + compteurFixe);
            indexItemFixe++;
            indexPositionFixe++;
            compteurFixe++;
        }
        else if (compteurMobile < itemMobile.Length && compteurFixe >= itemFixe.Length)
        {
            Debug.Log("Boucle ITEM MOBILE ");
            Debug.Log("indexArrayItemMobile " + indexItemMobile);
            Debug.Log("indexPositionItemMobile " + indexPositionMobile);
            Debug.Log("compteur de la boucle IF " + compteurMobile);
            Destroy(Instantiate(itemMobile[indexItemMobile], spawnPointMobile[indexPositionMobile].position, spawnPointMobile[indexPositionMobile].rotation), 4);
            Debug.Log("Item spawned : " + compteurMobile);
            indexItemMobile++;
            indexPositionMobile++;
            compteurMobile++;
        }
        else if (compteurMixte < itemMixte.Length && compteurFixe >= itemFixe.Length && compteurMobile >= itemMobile.Length)
        {
            Debug.Log("Boucle ITEM MIXTE");
            Debug.Log("indexArrayItemMixte " + indexItemMixte);
            Debug.Log("indexPositionItemMixte " + indexPositionMixte);
            Debug.Log("compteur de la boucle IF " + compteurMixte);
            Destroy(Instantiate(itemMixte[indexItemMixte], spawnPointMixte[indexPositionMixte].position, spawnPointMixte[indexPositionMixte].rotation), 4);
            Debug.Log("Item spawned : " + compteurMixte);
            indexItemMixte++;
            indexPositionMixte++;
            compteurMixte++;
        }
        else { print("No More Item"); }

    }

    //Function to randomize array's of gameObject
    public static void RandomizeArray<T>(T[] array)
    {
        int size = array.Length; // initialize Size used in the for function
        for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
        {
            int indexToSwap = Random.Range(z, size);
            T swapValue = array[z];
            array[z] = array[indexToSwap];
            array[indexToSwap] = swapValue;
        }
    }

// If the path changes during the game, update the distance travelled so that the follower's position on the new path
// is as close as possible to its position on the old path
void OnPathChanged()
    {
        distanceTravelled = pathCreator.path.GetClosestDistanceAlongPath(transform.position);
    }

    //End of Script
}
```

Comment: Feel free [to accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) if you would like

Answer (score 1):

You could nest coroutines.

```
[SerializeField] Follower follower;
List<GameObject> objectsToShow = new List<GameObject>();

IEnumerator Tick()
{
    while (objectsToShow.Count > 0)
    {
        int[] seconds = { 4, 8, 12 };
        int idx = Random.Range(0, seconds.Length);

        int secondsToWait = seconds[idx];

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsToWait);
        follower.Walk();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsToWait);
        follower.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, here is the trick : 
I need my FPS to walk for "secondsToWait" time, not stop or wait. Which mean i cant use WaitForSeconds in a coroutine.

And after this "SecondsToWait" time walking, it has to stop for 4 seconds (and during this time, an object appear somewhere on the screen)

Comment: @Anghille yeah, so implement your moving logic in the follower script. Keep this logic in a separate script that controls the follower. `Follower.Walk()` can be a coroutine, or it could be a method that sets a `isWalking` bool.

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't quite get the answer. What do i have to do exactly (sorry for having some much trouble getting everything working ><)

Comment: @Anghille isolate your problem, create a simple script with a coroutine that waits for another coroutine to complete with `yield return`. Hopefully, the code I posted will make more sense then.

Comment: You could also use a `WaitWhile` and an anonymous lambda function that causes walking behavior before checking duration and returning true/false.